# Как сделать Get-запрос?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать get-запрос на Java для Android и получить ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать новый объект `URL` и вызвать на нем метод `.openStream()`

```
new URL("http://hashcode.ru").openStream()
```

Comment: Только мне кажется подозрительным написание `http://` дважды?

Comment: @Qwertiy: 99% это был баг миграции. Поправил (пришлось еще дописывать буквы, чтобы набрать длину нужную)